# CorePlot CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic and NSDate

Tags: ios, core-plot

I just want to know if it is possible to use NSDate and labelFormatter for axislabels while using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, although the automatic labeling algorithm doesn't know about the dates, so it won't split the axis into "nice" date intervals like days or weeks. You will probably want to use `CPTTimeFormatter` or `CPTCalendarFormatter` as the `labelFormatter`.

Comment: great. is there any link I can get help from? The examples are quite simple. What I want to achieve is to transfrom some timestamps into for example 08:00, 08:05, 08:10,.... and if you pinch back they become 08:00 09:00 10:00 and more pinch might change them even to 08:00, 10:00, 12:00 ...